# Best practice when creating classes that are solely in charge of the creation of other objects i.e. factories?

Tags: c#, refactoring, dry

I often find myself creating classes that I suffix with 'Factory'. These classes tend to be solely in charge of the creation of a specific class or set of related classes. However I've always felt that this probably isn't best practice and that there's a better way of approaching this. One of the reasons that I believe that this isn't best practice is down to the fact that although I am using the 'Factory' suffix I am not actually making use of the factory design pattern.

Let's say I have an class `Vehicle`, that contains two variables `make` and `model`. I want my problem to be able to create a number of these `Vehicle` objects, so I want to encapsulate the code to create these objects in a single class. I might create the below class.

```
public class VehicleFactory
{
    public Vehicle CreateVehicle(string make, string model)
    {
         //create vehicle..
         return vehicle;
    }
}
```

The `VehicleFactory` can then be used wherever I want in my program without repeating the code and violating DRY.

I often need to create these kind of factory classes when I'm refactoring code, more specifically when I find two or more classes that are creating the same objects. I'd want to refactor the code by pulling out the repeated code and then placing it inside a specific factory class.

Is there a better way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Factory` pattern is rather for more complicated scenarios, such as having common interface for concrte classes, then `Factory` class would create approprite objects of concrete class.

In your scenario the code could be placed directly in constructor of a class.

Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for example :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 common approaches for object creation:

1. Constructors
2. Static factory methods
3. Factory classes (not talking about Abstract Factory pattern, since you already identified that you're not using it)

I believe this list is also in priority order. Constructors should be preferred because it is the most obvious place where a developer would look when looking to instantiate an object. The downside is that constructors have a few limitations: the name must match the class name which limits overloading, and a constructor must "return" the class being constructed.

If you need to provide multiple overloads with the same signature, this is where static factory methods can be useful (or just for providing more descriptive method names in general). For example: `CreateVehicleWithName(string name)` and `CreateVehicleWithColor(string color)` would be impossible to do with constructors. Another case is where you want to allow returning `null` if parameters are invalid or some other result object instead of an instance of the class itself. Note that these static factory methods are often best defined as part of the class.

Finally, defining separate factory classes can be useful when you have a class with complex construction requirements where the constructor logic far exceeds the rest of the class' code. Factory classes are also useful if construction requires a lot of additional dependencies. However, the downside of these classes is that developers need to somehow discover them and proliferation of factories can lead to a lot of additional complexity.

In summary, best practice: define a constructor if you can; use a factory class only when constructors and static factory methods are not feasible.